# Got an error - Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

It's imposible to use pagespeed insights. When I'm trying use it with this link - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fnevatrip.ru%2F ang I got an error -

> Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: APP::1: Abnormal renderer
>   termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1.

SSL is valid.